# Error code when joining tables on id and date

Tags: sql, database, join, google-bigquery

I'm new to sql and am not sure what is going on. I'm trying to join two tables in BigQuery, where both tables have id numbers and dates.

One table was information of the amount of calories a user consumes in a day, while the other table provides how far they traveled while walking or running. For example:

| id | date | calories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6775888955 | 2016-04-26 | 3410 |
| 6962181067 | 2016-04-21 | 2867 |

| id | date | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6775888955 | 2016-04-26 | 5.269981 |
| 6962181067 | 2016-04-21 | 9.710038 |

So, I wrote the following lines...

```
SELECT calories.id, calories.day, calories.calories, distance_info.total_distance
FROM `fitbitproject18677.daily.calories` 
FULL JOIN `fitbitproject18677.daily.distance_info` ON calories.id = distance_info.id and calories.day = distance_info.day
```

Hoping to get...

| id | date | calories | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6775888955 | 2016-04-26 | 3410 | 5.269981 |
| 6962181067 | 2016-04-21 | 2867 | 9.710038 |

But instead I got the following error:

```
Cannot access field id on a value with type INT64 at [3:64]
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on or how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with ambiguity: in your code `calories` is name of a table, and a column in that table. Use aliases to avoid ambiguity:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.day, c.calories, d.total_distance
FROM `fitbitproject18677.daily.calories` c
FULL JOIN `fitbitproject18677.daily.distance_info` d 
  ON c.id = d.id and c.day = d.day
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following table definitions:

```
USE [stackoverflow]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calories](
    [SessionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SessionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Calories] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [SessionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Distance](
    [SessionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SessionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Distance] [decimal](12,6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [SessionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

and populating with the following dataset:

```
insert into Calories (sessionid, sessiondate, calories)
values (6775888955, DATEFROMPARTS(2016, 04, 26), 3410);
insert into Calories (sessionid, sessiondate, calories)
values (6962181067, DATEFROMPARTS(2016, 04, 21), 2867);

insert into Distance(sessionid, sessiondate, distance)
values (6775888955, DATEFROMPARTS(2016, 04, 26), 5.269981);
insert into Distance(sessionid, sessiondate, distance)
values (6962181067, DATEFROMPARTS(2016, 04, 21), 9.710038);
```

You should be able to join based upon the SessionId, I don't understand why you would want/need to join on the date.

```
select  *
from    Calories C
join    Distance D on D.SessionId = C.SessionId
```

If you do need to join on the date, then it would look like this:

```
select  *
from    Calories C
join    Distance D on D.SessionId= C.SessionId and D.SessionDate = C.SessionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of join two tables you have to select all columns from both tables, so use "*". You don't need to use the word 'Full' in the query. Try below query;

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id AND table1.date = table2.date;
 -- (where table1 = calories and table2 = distance in your case)
```